# Will the AKS Service CIDR be routed to the virtual appliance?

Tags: azure-aks

Have a private AKS cluster (on its own subnet) with a hub vnet that has a virtual appliance (azure firewall, hub is correctly peered).

AKS uses Azure CNI for networking.

If the subnet has a 0.0.0.0/0 route table rule that has next hop of Virtual Application (the firewall), will the AKS Service CIDR (172.18.0.0/15) be routed to the virtual appliance by the UDR 0.0.0.0/0 rule?

My assumption here is that the Service CIDR is not routed outside the cluster.

Comment: I have a comparable setup and it seems that with a 0.0.0.0/0 route to the firewall, the service cidr traffic is erroneously routed to the firewall. I would like to learn how to set up the route table in such way that the service cidr traffic is kept in the cluster.

Comment: Interesting, it's good to see this isn't an isolated issue. Opened a case with MS about this but they were unable to give a conclusive answer about this. My guess is there is some reason the service traffic is routed to the firewall during a loading process for route tables or such.